# Programmatically obtain DNS servers of host

Tags: c++, cross-platform, dns

Using C++, I would like to obtain the DNS servers being used by a host for three operating systems: OS X, FreeBSD, and Windows. I'd like confirmation that the approaches below are indeed best practice, and if not, a superior alternative.

- **OS X**: [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260518/finding-dns-server-settings-programmatically-on-mac-os-x/260534#260534); updated link at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_UnderstandSchema/SC_UnderstandSchema.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001065-CH203-TPXREF103)
- **Windows**: [`GetNetworkParams`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365968(VS.85).aspx)
- **FreeBSD**: `/etc/resolv.conf`

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: On Windows, a better function is `GetAdaptersAddresses()`.  It'll return both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and give you a ton of other information too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On many unix systems (linux, bsd) you can use the resolver functions to obtain the list of DNS servers: [man 3 resolver](http://linux.die.net/man/3/resolver).

After calling `res_init()` the resolver structure is initialized. The resolver structure stores all the information you need. The list of DNS servers are stored in the struct entry `nsaddr_list`.

The exact specification of the resolver structure can most likely be found in `resolv.h`.

Using the resolver functions is the preferred way to obtain the list of DNS servers. `res_init()` will most likely fill the resolver structure with the information found in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Also see [Use of resolv.h](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11371965/1531971)

Comment: Yep, this does seem of the preferred way to get the DNS servers though the *nix API. Thanks!

Comment: use res_ninit and res_nclose, not depend on global state variables.

Comment: Is there any good alternative to res_ninit( ). There are problems that i am seeing such as - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579030/retrieve-ipv4-and-ipv6-nameservers-programmatically