# ANSI C How to get name server (DNS) address in linux?

Tags: c, linux, dns, ip-address

I want to use in my code local DNS addresses and am looking for a library that would produce it. Is there anything like it or do I have to parse /etc/resolv.conf myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [the resolver functions](http://linux.die.net/man/3/resolver) as described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2916675/471164) or read the addresses of name servers from the file `/etc/resolv.conf` which is a simple text file, such as

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver x.x.x.x
nameserver y.y.y.y
```

where `x.x.x.x` and `y.y.y.y` are ip addresses.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I Finally used the links you provided plus functions described [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet_ntopman.html).

Answer (score 2):

Check http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fresninit.htm for some sample code.

Comment: This was also helpful, thanks!