# Programmatically obtain DNS IPv6 servers of host

Tags: c++, windows, dns, ipv6

I would like to obtain IPv6 addresses of DNS servers in system.

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916675/programmatically-obtain-dns-servers-of-host) helped me very much with IPv4.

But `GetNetworkParams()` is not returning IPv6 servers, only IPv4. Is there any other way to do this?

**EDIT:**
I found [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915(v=vs.85).aspx) which fills a `PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` structure, that contains `IP_ADAPTER_DNS_SERVER_ADDRESS` structure. Then you can just use `getnameinfo()` to convert IP to String.

Answer (score 0):

I think `getaddrinfo()` might work:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520.aspx