# Retrieve IPv4 and IPv6 nameservers programmatically

Tags: linux, gcc, dns, ipv6, libresolv

I'm trying to use libresolv to read both the IPv4 and IPv6 nameservers in my `/etc/resolv.conf` file:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
nameserver 2001:4860:4860:0:0:0:0:8888
```

This is my C program:

```
#include <resolv.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    res_state res = malloc(sizeof(struct __res_state));
    res_ninit(res);

    printf("IPv4 nscount:  %d\n", res->nscount);
    printf("IPv6 nscount6: %d\n", res->_u._ext.nscount6);

    return 0;
}
```

Which produces this output:

```
IPv4 nscount:  2
IPv6 nscount6: 0
```

Which surprises me. Why is it counting the IPv6 address as an IPv4 address?

GDB shows that the second address is zeroed out:

```
(gdb) display res.nsaddr_list[0]
5: res.nsaddr_list[0] = {sin_family = 2, sin_port = 13568, sin_addr = {s_addr = 889192575}, sin_zero = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"}
(gdb) display res.nsaddr_list[1]
6: res.nsaddr_list[1] = {sin_family = 0, sin_port = 0, sin_addr = {s_addr = 0}, sin_zero = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"}
```

Can anyone help me understand this behavior?

Comment: Warning: these are ancient BSD functions which are present for compatibility purposes. For anything you're currently writing, you really should use getaddrinfo() and its friends.

Comment: If you want what's in the `/etc/resolv.conf` file, wouldn't it be a whole lot easier to just open it and read its contents?

Comment: @MichaelHampton getaddrinfo() is a blocking call that isn't suitable in many cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should not access the `_u._ext` parts of the resolver state, they are an internal implementation detail.  The `nscount6` member is currently unused and always zero.  It had to be kept to avoid changing the ABI as the result of struct offset/size changes.

If you need the nameserver list, you should parse `/etc/resolv.conf` yourself.  Note that eventually, glibc will also support more than three name servers, and those extra resolvers will not be reflected in the public resolver state.

Comment: Is there a good alternative to res_ninit( ). I am currently parsing resolv.conf but would prefer to be interfacing to resolv.conf through a published API. The reason is that i can parse resolv.conf to get IP Addresses for Manual DNS. But for DHCP DNS, we really need a published API. So it will be great to use a single API that will do both Manual DNS and DHCP DNS.

Comment: DHCP clients typically rewrite `/etc/resolv.conf` in some way, so if you parse that, you should be good. It may give you `127.0.0.1` if there is a local cache, but that's fine because it's the resolver you should use. Any API would likely be more complicated than parsing `/etc/resolv.conf` directly.

Comment: I tested it. DNS acquired from a DHCP server is not written into resolv.conf. only API such as res_ninit( ) is able to get it over the network from the DHCP server.

Comment: Post a different question, please. It's obviously not for the same operating system.

Comment: It is the same for even Linux. Run the same program given by drautb in ubuntu and try changing contents of /etc/resolv.conf