# Alternative to glibc Library call res_ninit for getting DNS details over DHCP

Tags: dns, glibc, resolve

Is there a good API alternative to `res_ninit`?
There are problems with this call because the `res->_u.ext.nscount6` and `res->nscount` do not reflect correct numbers.  Adding a IPv6 address to `/etc/resolv.conf` still results in the `nscount` increasing where you would have expected the `nscount6` to increase.

An older glibc version seems to increase both `nscount` and `nscount6` for a IPv6 address in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

I am currently parsing `resolv.conf` directly because i am unable to depend on the `res_ninit` call. But this is fine for Manual DNS.

When it comes to DHCP DNS, then i need an API to give me the result. There is no other way (that i can think of) to determine the DNS IP addresses over DHCP.

Tried posting in other places within the board but not of help so far. E.g.

[Retrieve IPv4 and IPv6 nameservers programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579030/retrieve-ipv4-and-ipv6-nameservers-programmatically/49601309?noredirect=1#comment96557007_49601309)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res_ninit` and `res_init` only ever read name server information from `/etc/resolv.conf`.  You can always get the same data name servers by parsing `/etc/resolv.conf` yourself and examining the `nameserver` lines.  If there is no `nameserver` line, the default `127.0.0.1` will be used.

I don't think it is necessary to provide an API for that because the file format is so simple that is likely *more* difficult to use the API than to read the file instead.

Name server assignment over DHCP is implemented by rewriting `/etc/resolv.conf` if there is no local caching resolver running on the machine.  The exact mechanism used for that is distribution-specific, e.g. Debian uses [`resolvconf`](https://manpages.debian.org/resolvconf) if it is installed.

If a local caching resolver is running on the system (such as dnsmasq or Unbound), name servers over DHCP can be directly configured in that caching resolver.  In this case, `/etc/resolv.conf` will keep pointing to the same name server, typically by listing `nameserver 127.0.0.1` or no name server information at all (which is the default).