# Get DNS server IP from iphone settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, dns

I try to find a way how to get my DNS server ip which appear under settings->wi-fi->details->DNS. I don't know if apple allow to get this info programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this on OS X and worked for me, (link to ibresolv.dylib as well)

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <dns.h>

- (NSString *) getDNSAddressesStr 
{
    NSMutableString *addressStr = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"DNS Addresses \n"];

    res_state res = malloc(sizeof(struct __res_state));

    int result = res_ninit(res);

    if ( result == 0 )
    {    
        for ( int i = 0; i < res->nscount; i++ )
        {
            NSString *s = [NSString stringWithUTF8String :  inet_ntoa(res->nsaddr_list[i].sin_addr)];
            [addressStr appendFormat:@"%@\n",s];
            NSLog(@"%@",s);
        }
    }
    else 
        [addressStr appendString:@" res_init result != 0"];

    return addressStr;
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question:) if I have more than 3 DNS server in iPhone settings, nscount is equal only 3, why is that?

Comment: Is there a way to make it work for IPv6 networks too ?

Comment: If you get a "_res_9_ninit_" referenced from error. See the answer below (and upvote!).

Comment: this code won't return IPv6 name servers, and as a result would likely now fail App store approval

Comment: Will the above code can be used in production app in App Store. Does it uses any private api's which may result in my app getting rejected?

Answer (score 10):

This is (IMHO) a better Swift3+ variant, which is an extract of my Swift wrapper for `libresolv` as used by [dig for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/isc-dig/id1115648880), and correctly handles IPV6 name servers:

```
open class Resolver {

    fileprivate var state = __res_9_state()

    public init() {
        res_9_ninit(&state)
    }

    deinit() {
        res_9_ndestroy(&state)
    }

    public final func getservers() -> [res_9_sockaddr_union] {

        let maxServers = 10
        var servers = [res_9_sockaddr_union](repeating: res_9_sockaddr_union(), count: maxServers)
        let found = Int(res_9_getservers(&state, &servers, Int32(maxServers)))

        // filter is to remove the erroneous empty entry when there's no real servers
       return Array(servers[0 ..< found]).filter() { $0.sin.sin_len > 0 }
    }
}
```

Converting a `res_9_sockaddr_union` to its string value can be done with this:

```
extension Resolver {
    public static func getnameinfo(_ s: res_9_sockaddr_union) -> String {
        var s = s
        var hostBuffer = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))

        len sinlen = socklen_t(s.sin.sin_len)
        let _ = withUnsafePointer(to: &s) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
                Darwin.getnameinfo($0, sinlen,
                                   &hostBuffer, socklen_t(hostBuffer.count),
                                   nil, 0,
                                   NI_NUMERICHOST)
            }
        }

        return String(cString: hostBuffer)
    }
}
```

which all combined can get a `String[]` containing the list of servers like this:

```
let servers = Resolver().getservers().map(Resolver.getnameinfo)
```

Comment: For symbols like `res_9_sockaddr_union`, which module should I import under Swift 3?

Comment: @JayZhao to link you'll need `libresolv.9.tbd`.  AFAICR the `_union` structure is imported automatically.

Comment: @JayZhao hmm, perhaps a bridging header is necessary, too

Comment: Great answer, but i have compiler warning in getnameinfo function.  It seems s.sin.sin_len is confusing for compiler, so i declare one more variable let lenght = s.sin.sin_len, and use it  socklen_t(lenght)

Comment: @MegaManX right - Swift 4.1 made this code illegal - I had the same problem on my released app.   I'll update this.

Comment: @Alnitak any update on "Swift 4.1 made this code illegal"

Comment: @MuhammadAliYousaf yes - I updated it the same day I made that comment.

Comment: @Alnitak Did you mean that, this code is legal in Swift 4.1 and will have no issue while releasing the app on AppStore? Right?

Comment: I can't promise you'll have no problem, but I have code in the AppStore that uses the above.

Answer (score 5):

ObjC version with IPV6 support if Swift is not in your project:

```
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netdb.h>

@implementation DNSResolver {
    res_state _state;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _state = malloc(sizeof(struct __res_state));
        if (EXIT_SUCCESS != res_ninit(_state)) {
            free(_state);
            return nil;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    res_ndestroy(_state);
    free(_state);
}

#pragma mark - Public

- (NSString *)getDNSAddressesCSV
{
    NSMutableArray *addresses = [NSMutableArray new];

    union res_sockaddr_union servers[NI_MAXSERV];

    int serversFound = res_9_getservers(_state, servers, NI_MAXSERV);

    char hostBuffer[NI_MAXHOST];
    for (int i = 0; i < serversFound; i ++) {
        union res_sockaddr_union s = servers[i];
        if (s.sin.sin_len > 0) {
            if (EXIT_SUCCESS == getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&s.sin,  // Pointer to your struct sockaddr
                                            (socklen_t)s.sin.sin_len,   // Size of this struct
                                            (char *)&hostBuffer,        // Pointer to hostname string
                                            sizeof(hostBuffer),         // Size of this string
                                            nil,                        // Pointer to service name string
                                            0,                          // Size of this string
                                            NI_NUMERICHOST)) {          // Flags given
                [addresses addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:hostBuffer]];
            }
        }
    }

    return [addresses componentsJoinedByString:@","];
}


@end
```

Answer (score -1):

This is Swift3 variant of the accepted answer:

```
func dnsServers() -> [in_addr_t] {
    var result = __res_9_state()
    guard res_9_ninit(&result) == 0 else { return [] }
    let sockets = result.nsaddr_list // note: nsaddr_list is a tuple, not an array
    let addresses = [sockets.0.sin_addr.s_addr, sockets.1.sin_addr.s_addr, sockets.2.sin_addr.s_addr]
    let filtered = addresses.filter { $0 != nil }
    return filtered
}
```

As usual, link `libresolv.9.tbd` and add `#import <resolv.h>` to bridging header

Answer (score -1):

Refer to the following Swift code to get DNS resolution for a website. One method uses `CFHostStartInfoResolution` whereas other one uses `gethostbyname`.

Both these APIs support all/multiple IP address resolution.

```
private func urlToIP_cfHostResolution(_ url: String) -> [String] {

    var ipList: [String] = []

    let host = CFHostCreateWithName(nil,url as CFString).takeRetainedValue()

    CFHostStartInfoResolution(host, .addresses, nil)

    var success: DarwinBoolean = false

    if let addresses = CFHostGetAddressing(host, &success)?.takeUnretainedValue() as NSArray? {

        for case let theAddress as NSData in addresses {

            var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))

            if getnameinfo(theAddress.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: sockaddr.self), socklen_t(theAddress.length),
                       &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count), nil, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0 {

                ipList.append(String(cString: hostname))
            }    
        }
    }

    return ipList
}
```

This method returns `["151.101.129.69", "151.101.1.69", "151.101.193.69", "151.101.65.69"]` for `www.stackoverflow.com`

```
private func urlToIP_gethostbyname(_ url: URL) -> [String] {

    var ipList: [String] = []

    guard let hostname = url.host else {

        return ipList
    }

    guard let host = hostname.withCString({gethostbyname($0)}) else {

        return ipList
    }

    guard host.pointee.h_length > 0 else {

        return ipList
    }

    var index = 0

    while host.pointee.h_addr_list[index] != nil {

        var addr: in_addr = in_addr()

        memcpy(&addr.s_addr, host.pointee.h_addr_list[index], Int(host.pointee.h_length))

        guard let remoteIPAsC = inet_ntoa(addr) else {

            return ipList
        }

        ipList.append(String.init(cString: remoteIPAsC))

        index += 1
    }

    return ipList
}
```

This method also returns `["151.101.129.69", "151.101.1.69", "151.101.193.69", "151.101.65.69"]` for `www.stackoverflow.com`

Hope this helps.