# iOS - Get device's DNS server address on IPv6 only network

Tags: ios, dns, ipv6, ipv4

I am trying to get device's DNS server address while connected to IPv6 only network on iOS. The following code works well for when connected to IPv4 network but doesn't work on IPv6 network. Code taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26982170/396949).

```
res_ninit(&_res);
res_state res = &_res;

for (int i=0; i < res->nscount; i++) {
    sa_family_t family = res->nsaddr_list[i].sin_family;

    if (family == AF_INET) {
      NSLog(@"IPv4");
      char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN]; // String representation of address
      inet_ntop(AF_INET, & (res->nsaddr_list[i].sin_addr.s_addr), str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    } else if (family == AF_INET6) {
      NSLog(@"IPv6");
      char address[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN]; // String representation of address
      inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(res->nsaddr_list [i].sin_addr.s_addr), address, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
    } else {
      NSLog(@"Unspecified");
    }
}
```

On IPv6 network, `sin_family` is always `AF_UNSPEC`. Any suggestions/alternatives?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @Neelesh Nope. Instead I ended up resolving hosts with CFHostStartInfoResolution instead of trying to get DNS server address.

Comment: @mrvincenzo see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41303040/6782

Answer (score 0):

Try using res._u._ext.nsaddrs for IPv6.

See https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/net/dns/dns_config_service_posix.cc#437