# How to call res_nquery function in playground?

Tags: swift

I want to convert the follow OC code to Swift in playground.But i can't be call

```
int len = res_nquery(res, host, ns_c_in, ns_t_a, answer, sizeof(answer));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code I have this Swift 3 wrapper:

```
public final func query(_ dname: String, qclass: UInt16, qtype: UInt16, answer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, anslen: Int) -> Int32 {
    return res_9_nquery(&state, dname, Int32(qclass), Int32(qtype), answer, Int32(anslen))
}
```

where `state` is:

```
var state = __res_9_state()
res_9_ninit(&state)
```

You will need to add `libresolv.9.dylib` to your project's libraries.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.jianshu.com/p/d945454e3abc

You need to add #include  on objective-c file header.

[Get DNS server IP from iphone settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256024/get-dns-server-ip-from-iphone-settings)

You need to know How import Objective-c in swift.

You need to create a objective-c functions for res_query.

In objective-c file , like as **.m,

- (NSUInteger) newForRes_query:(char *)domainName newclass:(int)class newtype:(int)type newanswer_buffer:(char *)answer_buffer newanswer_buffer_length:(int)answer_buffer_length
  {
  int nBytesRead = 0;
  nBytesRead = res_query(domainName,class,type,answer_buffer,answer_buffer_length);
  return nBytesRead;
  }

Comment: #include can't be use in Swift.

Comment: So you need to make function to input things for # include.